# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute -- attribute error

Tags: spring-mvc

I was following a tutorial and I got this error

```
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
```

Here is the code that I am using.

```
<form:form action="saveCustomer" ModelAttribute="customer" method="POST">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>First name:</label></td>
                        <td><form:input path="firstName"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Last name:</label></td>
                        <td><form:input path="lastName"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Email:</label></td>
                        <td><form:input path="email"/></td>
                    </tr>   
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form:form>
```

this is the customer-form to add a new customer, the problem occurs at **firstName input**

the get method to show the form is:

```
@GetMapping("/showFormForAdd")
    public String showFormForAdd(Model theModel) {
        Customer theCustomer = new Customer();
        theModel.addAttribute("customer", theCustomer);
        return "customer-form";
    }
```

and the customer entity is:

```
@Column(name="first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name="last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name="email")
private String email;
```

in the error it says **bean name 'command'** so I changed the name of the attribute to command and it worked, but why it does not work if I used customer.
in the tutorial he did not use command.

Comment: try using camel case convention `modelAttribute="customer"`.

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt thank you, it solved the problem. I just lost 1h for a silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using camel case convention `modelAttribute="customer"`. Otherwise, it is expected to be `command`-named model by default, i.e. `model.addAttribute("command", customer);`, which you need to send as a model.